# Computer freezes with buzzing noise

Tags: audio, freeze

I've recently build a new computer (few weeks back), for virtualization aswell for gaming.

But the past 2 nights while gaming the computer freezes with a loud noise coming through my speakers. It occured on 2 different games, CS:GO and the latest Tomb Raider. Now I know it is not a overheating problem since my temps are never going over de 55c. My drivers are also up to date.

Now I never had any problems with any other gaming/virtualization system I build, it's the first time. It's completely random, and not outside of gaming.

Part list:

be quiet! POWERZONE 850W

Corsair 16 GB DDR4-2400 Kit (2x8GBx2, 4 bars)

Noctua NH-D14

MSI 4GB D5 X GTX970 Gaming 4G

Intel Core i7-6700K @4.0Ghz

Asus Z170 PRO GAMING Z170

Windows 8.1 64-Bit

Comment: Classic symptom of under-power or over-heat. GPU crash. The "buzzing" is the last part of the currently playing sound being repeated over & over.

Comment: To add to the above, if you have [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), you should see high CPU activity for the `System -> Interrupts` process.

Comment: Overheat is not a problem, same as the high CPU activity. While under heavy gaming is wont go above the 60%.

Comment: Can you look in event viewer and find the logs where it hangs? Try checking the hard drive. I didnt see you mention the hard drive.

Comment: Sorry about that, event viewer mentions nothing at the time of the crash other the firewall exceptions of steam and others related.  But nothing about any hardware. The harddrive could be related to the crash as it is 6 years old (500GB WD Blue). Used an old one.

Comment: Is the RAM listed as tested/compatible? Overclocked? I once used four bars of a RAM type which was only listed as tested/compatible with four bars... and... well... have a guess. -- And congrats for choosing the Noctua, if a personal remark like this is not deemed totally inappropriate here.

Comment: RAM is tested and compatible. None of my components is overclocked. I love Noctua, I have had it in almost every system I have build.

Comment: Test your power supply by multi-meter, check the colored wires that goes to your mother board, you can find the right value on your power supply for each color, for me it seems not enough power..